# 'D-Hoppers', magic, parallel universes - comedy book series in a similar style to T. Pratchett?

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

The book series starts with a young guy trying to master magic in the hut of his master. He's been trying to light a candle with his mind for months but failed miserably.
Next thing he knows a 'demon' appears, gives him some pointers, and whisks the guy away on a series of adventures across parallel universes.
The tool used for this was referred to as a 'd-hopper', or dimension hopper.

In these parallel universes the competent use of magic is rare and the guy soon becomes the best magician around, even though he has little to no skill with it.
Adventures ensure, friends and enemies are made, and the guy's magic develops.

One universe the story leads us to consists of a world of ugly-looking large snails, and disguising themselves with magic, the protagonists are forced to walk incredibly slowly.

The series is a trilogy (I think), it's a comedy and I remember reading it in my early teenage years

Does anyone have a clue what it is? I've wanted to re-find this book for at least a decade, if not more!

Comment: I'm at a loss why this attracted a downvote.

Comment: Me too. It's a good question, which has the salient details that lead to you (and me) immediately jumping on the answer.

Comment: semi-duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147153/identify-a-story-about-a-teen-boy-who-learns-to-use-magic-with-his-lizard-compan (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 12):

[Another Fine Myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_Fine_Myth) by Robert Lynn Asprin (and later co-authored by Jody Lynn Nye), part of the nineteen book "[MythAdventures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythAdventures)" series

Per wikipedia

> Back on Klah, Quigley, the demon hunter, joins their troupe. The five
>   would-be heroes and the dragon Gleep and Quigley's war unicorn
>   Buttercup confront Isstvan and defeat him by tricking him into
>   consuming wine that destroys his magical ability. **The defeated Isstvan
>   and his allies leave Klah using a D-Hopper, a device that allows the
>   user(s) to hop between dimensions.** Tananda and Quigley leave too.
>   Skeeve and Aahz remain at the Inn, and Aahz begins teaching his new
>   apprentice more of the mastery of Magic.

and

> Aahz, a green, scaly **"demon" (short for "dimension traveler")** from the
>   dimension of Perv, a world known for its foul-tempered reptilian
>   humanoid inhabitants . Aahz (short for Aahzmandius) takes Skeeve on as
>   his apprentice, despite having lost his powers through a prank pulled
>   by Skeeve's now-deceased mentor, Garkin, at the beginning of the first
>   novel. Later on, he and Skeeve dissolve their mentor/apprentice
>   relationship and become partners in a magician-for-hire enterprise
>   called M.Y.T.H. Inc.

Comment: ^_^ Fanon count for the 12 books in the first series and the 8 or so in the second one?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Edited [accordingly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythAdventures). I recall losing interest about ten pages in when I tried to read them.