# Identify a story about a teen boy who learns to use magic with his lizard companion

Tags: story-identification, books

Can you help me identify a book I read?  It was intended for teenagers.  I believe I read it in the late 1980s or early 1990s.

The main character is a teenage human boy from earth, who is learning to use magic with the help of a humanoid lizard companion, who knows all about magic, but can't use magic himself.  They travel to numerous worlds.

I remember one of the lessons was to draw in magic from the ground with every step he takes.  And there are different lines or streams of magic flowing through the world.  Different areas have different concentrations of magic to draw from.

At one point they travel to another world where there is a bazaar or marketplace selling lots of different things.

I believe at one point they travel to yet another world where they are hanged.  The main character survives by lifting himself up by using magic, and the lizard companion uses his strong neck muscles to avoid being killed.

I believe there's also a house where the front door is in one world, but the rest of the house is in a different world.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It sounds like [*Myth Adventures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythAdventures). The "lizard" is a scaled "demon" (dimensional traveler) named Aahz from the world of Perv. In the first book, *[Another Fine Myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_Fine_Myth)*, indeed Aahz teaches Skeeve (who is actually from the medieval fantasy world of Klah) to use ley lines to pull in magic. They visit the Bazaar on Deva, but before that, on Klah, they are sentenced to be hanged. Skeeve survives by levitating himself and Aahz survives due to strong neck muscles.

The house with the doors that go different places shows up in *[Mything Persons](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/461627.Myth_ing_Persons)*, where they learn that a door in the house goes to Limbo, which is filled with vampires.

Comment: MythAdventures is an entire series.  Can you identify which book in the series he's talking about?  Maybe add some more detail on what matches up?

Comment: That looks like it.  I may be combining several books of the series together.

Comment: How might a consenting adult get to this "world of Perv?"

Comment: One discrepancy is that Skeeve is a Klahd (clod) from Klah.  He is not from Earth.  Though Klah is a fairly generic-ish medieval-Europe fantasy world.

Comment: @Mystagogue "Another Fine Myth" was published in 1978, which (according to Wikipedia) mentions "Perv" by name. I assume back then it didn't have the association it does today? I'm guessing that name would *not* get published today.

Comment: @Mystagogue - You don't want to go there, it's full of "Pervects" who get angry if you suggest things about consenting adults and their world's name.

Comment: @Jim "Perv" certainly had very similar connotations in 1978 to what it does now (indeed as a reference to someone who is sexually perverted I think the term is very old). I don't see why there would be any issue with publishing a book that used the term (even in a title), then or now.