# Book last read in 2000 involving a boy named Zeek I think who was training to be a wizard and visits a dimension called the bazaar

Tags: story-identification, novel, wizards

I am looking for a book I last read in around the year 2000.  It involved a boy who was training to be a wizard.  his name was Zeek or something like that.  He visits a dimension called the bazaar where people can buy anything for the right price.  He fights a person who uses magic rings.  I want to re-read this and can not remember the title. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Might the name have been "[Skeeve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythAdventures)"?

Comment: Wow!  That is it!  I was googling it and because I had the name wrong nothing would come up.  Glad someone out there knew what I was talking about...lol.  I had not remembered or realized that this book was part of a series.  It had been so long.  I just remembered that I liked the book.  With the answer provided I was able to easily find the book and I see there are a ton of them from the series for sale.  I will definitely be making sure to pick them up.  You made my day.  Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the character's name is *Skeeve* and his partner is named "Aahz" then you read one of Robert Lynn Asprin's *Myth* books, possibly [*Myth Directions*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2548) which is the book that introduces Massha, another wizard who primarily fights with magic devices and as a result wears a lot of rings:

> "You misunderstand me." Massha waved, fanning the air with a massive hand. "What I meant was, take off your disguises."
>
> "Our disguises?" I blurted, swallowing hard.
>
> In reply, she held aloft her left hand, **the index finger extended for us to see. The third—no, it was the fourth—ring was blinking a brilliant purple.**
>
> "This little toy says you're not only magicians, you're disguised," she grinned. "Now, I'm as sociable as the next person but I like to see who I'm doing business with. In fact, I insist!"
>
> As she spoke, the door behind us slammed shut and locked with an audible click.

Skeeve is Aahz' apprentice after his previous master (Garkin) was killed. In each book he learns a bit more magic, from creating fire, to levitation, disguise spells...

[image: Cover of "Myth Directions" with Skeeve at the door of their house on Klah and Aahz looking out the window as a unicorn chases Gleep]

Most of the books involve a trip (or more) to the dimension "Deva" (where "Deevels" come from) where they visit the Bazaar, an endless souk where you can buy anything:

> Anyway, there is a year-round, rock-the-clock Bazaar in that dimension where the Deveels meet to trade with each other. Everything imaginable and most things that aren't are available there. All you have to do is bargain with the Deveels. Fortunately, the Bazaar is large enough that there is much duplication, and sometimes you can play the dealers off against each other.

Comment: Another Q&A about the series  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147153/identify-a-story-about-a-teen-boy-who-learns-to-use-magic-with-his-lizard-compan?rq=1

Comment: @FreeMan Ah, nice catch, thanks.  "Her" -> "he"